# Need SQL query/script to give me a distinct count per column for every column in one table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a query/script to just display a distinct count of values in each column of a table. I'm using it to tie out to a legacy report where each column is a two way freq of the column by disctinct count. Something like below:

```
select distinct field1,count(*)
from EBL_CLIENT.EAP_FACT
where run_id = '205572'

select distinct field2,count(*)
from EBL_CLIENT.EAP_FACT
where run_id = '205572'

select distinct fieldetc...,count(*)
from EBL_CLIENT.EAP_FACT
where run_id = '205572'
```

Comment: This is typically done with `SELECT column, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY column`.

Comment: It may be hard to get a count of values for **all** columns, because you cannot get a distinct count if a column is of type CLOB, LOB, BLOB, LONG, XML, Object, nested table etc...

Comment: Yeah I'm just trying to minimize queries I have to run. I'm not too experienced in SQL to know if there is a script I can run that can give me the distinct value count per field for the EAP_FACT Table.  There are like 117 different fields.

Comment: If you have 117 different columns in 1 table then you probably need to re-think your database structure.

Comment: Database structure isn't my problem to worry about. My job is just to tie out counts. Just looking for an efficient way to do it instead of running 117 queries.

Comment: @dag06001 More efficient in terms of writing 117 queries? Or the actual executing of 117 queries?

Comment: Just a thought, but would be easier with a C# (or any language) console app. I realize it may not be in your tool box, but maybe a co-worker.

Comment: `select distinct field1,count(*)` is not giving you a distinct count (apart from the fact that the query would generate an error). You are looking for `select field1, count(*) ... group by field1`.

Answer (score 1):

Please find below script for generating SQL query:

```
declare
  v_col varchar2(64) := 'run_id';
  v_val varchar2(64) := '205572';
  v_table varchar2(64) := 'EAP_FACT';
  v_schema varchar2(64) := 'EBL_CLIENT';
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('select *'||chr(10)||'from (select ');
  for i in (select t.COLUMN_NAME, rownum rn
            from all_tab_columns t 
            where t.TABLE_NAME = upper(v_table)
              and t.OWNER = upper(v_schema)
              and t.COLUMN_NAME <> upper(v_col)
            order by t.COLUMN_ID)
    loop
      dbms_output.put_line('            '||case when i.rn=1 then ' ' else ',' end||
                           'count(distinct '||i.column_name||') '||i.column_name);
    end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('      from '||v_schema||'.'||v_table||' t where t.'||v_col||' = '''||v_val||''')'
                       ||chr(10)||'unpivot'||chr(10)||'(cnt');
  for i in (select listagg (t.COLUMN_NAME,',') within group (order by t.COLUMN_ID) lst
            from all_tab_columns t 
            where t.TABLE_NAME = upper(v_table)
              and t.OWNER = upper(v_schema)
              and t.COLUMN_NAME <> upper(v_col))
    loop
      dbms_output.put_line('    '||'for col in ('||i.lst||')');
    end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line(')'||chr(10)||'order by cnt desc');
end;
```

You will get some query like this:

```
select *
from (select 
             count(distinct t.field1) field1 
            ,count(distinct t.field2) field2
            ,count(distinct t.field3) field3
      from EBL_CLIENT.EAP_FACT t where t.run_id = '205572')
unpivot
(cnt
    for col in (field1,field2,field3)
)
order by cnt desc
```

And after run this query result will be like this:

```
col     cnt
field2  5
field1  3
field3  1
```

Answer (score 0):

This would give the results for each column in a single row

```
select Field1Count = count(distinct field1)
,Field2Count = count(distinct field2)
,fieldetcCount = count(fieldetc)
from EBL_CLIENT.EAP_FACT
where run_id = '205572'
```

Comment: `Field1Count = count(distinct field1)` is invalid SQL (in the SQL standard and in Oracle)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps as it will still run 117 queries but you won't have to manually create them. Run the query which will return 117 select statements. Copy them and run them to get the counts.

```
SELECT 'SELECT ''' || COLUMN_NAME || ''' AS ColumnName , COUNT(DISTINCT ' 
  || COLUMN_NAME || ') AS Count FROM ' || Table_Schema || '.' || Table_Name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'EBL_CLIENT'
  AND TABLE_NAME = 'EAP_FACT'
```

Comment: The string concatenation operator in SQL is `||` not `+`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  sorry was thinking SQL server